# Javascript - Why does this function loop twice?

Tags: jquery, animation

Trying to solve that problem, but no luck for hours...

I have

```
var screen1 = $('#screen');
var screen2 = $('#screen_teams');
var screen3 = $('#field_position');
. . .

screenFade(screen1,1000,1);
function screenFade(screen,delay,next) {
    if (next == 1) {
        screen.delay(delay).fadeOut(1000, function() {animation(2);console.log('2');});
    } else {
        screen.fadeIn(1000).delay(delay).fadeOut(1000, function() {animation(next);console.log(next);});
    }
}
function animation(seq) {
    if (seq == 2) {
        screenFade(screen2,2000,3);
    };
    if (seq == 3) {
        screenFade(screen3,2000,4);
    };
    if (seq == 4) {
        screenFade(screen4,2000,5);
    };
}
```

And firebug outputs:
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5

Do you know the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that overall this code's getting called twice?

Comment: the original call is here:

$('.1,.2').cycle({
  fx: ''+Animation1+'',
  sync: 1,
  timeout: 2000,
  autostop: 1,
  autostopCount: 2,
  end: function() {
      screenFade(screen1,1000,1);
  }
});

Now i found the problem. If i remove .2, everything works fine. Got one "AH-HA!!" moment. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your biggest issue is the recursive nature of your code... I think a little simplification is in order.

If you put all of your "screens" as child elements of a parent then you can easily use a rotate plugin I wrote for jQuery:

If the parent element had an ID of `screens` and each screen was a child `div` then you could use the plugin like this:

```
function() rotateCallback(screenNumber, screen) {
    if(screenNumber == 4)
        callOtherFunction();
}

$(function() {
    $("#screens div").Rotate({ cycleTime: 2000, fadeTime: 1000, callback: rotateCallback});
})
```

On the window load event this will select all of the child divs of the parent with an ID of `screens` and then rotate every 2 seconds fading over 1 second.

Here's the plugin code:

```
jQuery.fn.Rotate = function(config) {
    var currentIdx = 0;
    var items = [];
    var itemCount = this.each(function(idx, item) {
        items.push($(item));
    }).length;

    function rotateItem()
    {
        var front = items[currentIdx];
        var back = items[currentIdx = ((currentIdx + 1) % itemCount)];

        back.fadeIn(config.fadeTime);
        front.fadeOut(config.fadeTime, function() { front.hide() });

        if(config.callback)
            config.callback(currentIdx, back);
    }
    setInterval(rotateItem, config.cycleTime);
}
```

**--Update--**

Added callback on rotation and example.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I need callbacks. At about 4th screen, the animation would need to stop and wait for another function to be executed. I fixed my problem now but, I'm I heading in the right way?

Comment: @c4rrt3r I added an example of how to do a callback and check which screen is showing by index, the callback also receives the index and jQuery element for the currently displayed screen if you need to operate on it.